# Pestañas dinámicas con Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

¿Por qué el primer ejemplo me funciona y el segundo no?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tab in $parent.tabs">{{tab.name}}</li>
</ul>

<uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab heading="Static title 1">Static content 1</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Static title 2">Static content 2</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in $parent.tabs" heading="tab.name">
        Dynamic Content
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

La directiva está funcionando porque las dos pestañas estáticas me las crea y las asocia a su contenido, pero no las dinámicas (Dynamic Tabs)...

`$parent.tabs` es un array de objetos.

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

te recomendaría encarecidamente que nunca uses $parent, principalmente porque no podes estar seguro a que hace referencia.

**¿Cual es el problema?**

En el caso de arriba, parent hace referencia al padre del view que estas usando (no se bien a cual porque no hay mas código, pero parecería ser que es al padre del controller actual), mientras que en el segundo ejemplo, $parent hace referencia al padre del componente actual, que es uib-tabset. si pruebas $parent.$parent.tabs me parece que va a funcionar.

**Solución**

Lo mejor para mi es usar controller as y definir en el controller actual el dato, por ejemplo en el controller podrías hacer algo así como

```
$scope.tabs = $scope.$parent.tabs;
```

(tendrias que in) y dentro del view simplemente

```
ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
```

Particularmente prefiero el controller as, en los controllers hago

```
vm = this;
vm.tabs = $scope.$parent.tabs;
```

y en el view

```
ng-repeat="tab in $ctrl.tabs"
```

Si nos compartís mas código podemos ayudarte mejor, si es un componente podes enviar los tabs como parametro, por ejemplo.

Comment: Claro, no me di cuenta de que en el segundo ejemplo el $parent hace referencia al padre del componente.... Gracias!

Comment: de nada @slinkybass. No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta. Saludos!